# Vector Iterator: no match for ‘operator=’

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

Considering the code C++ in the first code snippet below, I am getting the compilation errors indicated in the second snippet. It looks I am doing st wrong when traversing the vector instance. Can you tell me how I can overcome these compilation problems? Thanks. LINE 171 is marked in the code.

**SNIPPET 1 (Code)**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class VipAddressSetEntity : BaseEntity
{
public:
      VipAddressSetEntity() : BaseEntity() { }
      VipAddressSetEntity(std::string &uuid, std::string &name) : BaseEntity(uuid, name) { }

      VipAddressSetEntity(const VipAddressSetEntity &copyin)
      {
       setUUID(copyin.getUUID());
       setName(copyin.getName());

       std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::iterator iter;
               /* LINE 171 is the following*/
       for( iter = copyin.mVipAddressList.begin(); iter !=   copyin.mVipAddressList.end(); iter++ )
       {
                addVipAddress(*iter);
       }
      }

      VipAddressSetEntity operator = (const VipAddressSetEntity &rhs)
      {
        setUUID(rhs.getUUID());
        setName(rhs.getName());

        std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::iterator iter;
        for( iter = rhs.mVipAddressList.begin(); iter != rhs.mVipAddressList.end(); iter++ )
        {
                addVipAddress(*iter);
        }

        return *this;
       }

       void addVipAddress(VipAddressEntity &entity)
       {
        mVipAddressList.push_back(entity);
           }

       VipAddressEntity & getVipAddress(std::string uuid)
       {
        std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::iterator iter;
        for( iter = mVipAddressList.begin(); iter != mVipAddressList.end(); iter++ )
        {
            if(iter->getUUID() == uuid)
            {
               return  *iter;
            }
        }

            return NULL;
         }


         const std::vector<VipAddressEntity>& getVipAddressList() const { return  mVipAddressList; }


 private:
    std::vector<VipAddressEntity> mVipAddressList;

};
```

**SNIPPET 2 (Compilation output)**

```
 Entity.hpp: In copy constructor   ‘ECLBCP::VipAddressSetEntity::VipAddressSetEntity(const ECLBCP::VipAddressSetEntity&)’:
 Entity.hpp:171:44: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘iter =    copyin.ECLBCP::VipAddressSetEntity::mVipAddressList.std::vector<_Tp,   _Alloc>::begin<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity, std::allocator<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity> >()’
 Entity.hpp:171:44: note: candidates are:
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:68:0,
                  from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                  from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:42,
                  from Entity.hpp:11:
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:710:11: note:  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity*,   std::vector<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity> >&  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity*,   std::vector<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity> >::operator=(const   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity*,   std::vector<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity> >&)
 /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_iterator.h:710:11: note:   no known conversion for     argument 1 from ‘std::vector<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity>::const_iterator {aka  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity*,  std::vector<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity> >}’ to ‘const  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity*,   std::vector<ECLBCP::VipAddressEntity> >&’
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`copyin` is a `const VipAddressSetEntity` and so `copyin.mVipAddressList` is also `const`. Calling `begin` on a `const std::vector<VipAddressEntity>` will give you an immutable iterator of type `std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::const_iterator`. Just make sure your `iter` is of that type too and you'll be able to assign to it just fine:

```
std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::const_iterator iter;
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
for( iter = copyin.mVipAddressList.begin(); iter !=   copyin.mVipAddressList.end(); iter++)
```

You can not assign a `std::vector<VipAddressEntity>::iterator` from `copyin.mVipAddressList.begin()` because `copyin` is const. Use a `const_iterator` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`copyin` is a const reference.  You should use a `const_iterator` to iterate.